# Data table greater than WellPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

How can I increase the size of the WellPanel to have my table completely inside the "grey" box?
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LrQp.png)

(I'm new in Shiny and edited the table due to confidential data).

I tried

```
wellPanel( 
  fluidRow(
    fluidPage(
```

and only

```
wellPanel( 
  fluidRow(
```

None of then works

```
wellPanel( 
  fluidRow(
    fluidPage(
      headerPanel(""), 
      column(12,  align="center",
             output$dataprint_controles <- DT::renderDataTable({
               datatable(data, 
                         rownames = FALSE,
                         options = list(paging = TRUE,
                                        scrollX = TRUE, 
                                        searching = TRUE,
                                        ordering = FALSE,
                                        autoWidth = FALSE,
                                        names = TRUE,
                                        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = esconder),
                                                          list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")
                                        ),
                                        dom = '<"sep">',
                                        headerCallback = DT::JS(stringr::str_glue(
                                          "function(thead) {{",
                                          "  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').css('border-top', '2px solid black');",
                                          "  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').css('border-left', '0px solid black');",
                                          "  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').css('background', '#D9D9D9');",
                                          "  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').css('color', 'black');",
                                          "  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').css('text-align', 'center');",
                                          "}}"
                                        ))
                         )
               ) 
             }),
      ),
    )
  ), # fecha fluid
), # fecha well panel
```

Answer (score 0):

`fluidPage` should be the most outer element of the UI, and `column` must be contained in `fluidRow`. The `wellPanel` does not go beyond a width of `100%`, so you have to add the CSS propert `width: fit-content;`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mat <- matrix(rnorm(5*14), nrow = 5, ncol = 14)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      12, 
      wellPanel(
        style = "width: fit-content;",
        DTOutput("dtable")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(mat)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```